# How to fix this error message occurring all the time during my non linear regression nlsLM method

Tags: r, ggplot2, exponential, non-linear-regression

I'm still trying to get  exponential curve lines on my data. I'm having abundance values in function of time and I want to apply and exponential regression on the first points. I've found a package since someone closed my previous post I don't know why.

My data :

| Day | C5 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 33804.52 |
| 0.84 | 39076.28 |
| 1.83 | 26521.87 |
| 3.83 | 118641.90 |
| 4.83 | 190218.34 |
| 5.82 | 327796.59 |
| 6.82 | 566427.37 |
| 7.85 | 1047815.21 |
| 8.82 | 1711886.33 |
| 9.82 | 2845895.73 |
| 10.82 | 2773359.88 |
| 11.82 | 3006184.04 |

Im

My code :

```
C5_abund <- read.csv(file = "C5_R.csv", sep=';')
C5_abund2 <- C5_abund[C5_abund$Day <= 9.82, ] #exponetial regresion applied on theses point

get_eqn <- function(fit) {
  eqn <- paste0("y = ", round(coef(fit)[1], 3), " * exp(", round(coef(fit)[2], 3), " * x)")
  return(eqn)
}


fitC5 <- nlsLM(C5 ~ a*exp(b*Day), data=C5_abund2, start=list(a=33804.52, b=0.5)) 
# using a= abundance at first day of experiment and b=theorical rate of growth
eqnC5 <- get_eqn(fitC5)
#y = 16470.994 * exp(0.525 * x)


rss <- sum(resid(fitC5)^2)
tss <- sum((C5_abund2$C5 - mean(C5_abund2$C5))^2)
rsq2C5 <- 1 - (rss/tss)

# rsq C5 :  0.9995


ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = C5_abund, aes(x = Day, y = C5),shape=16) +
  geom_smooth(data = C5_abund2, aes(x = Day, y = C5), method = "nlsLM", 
              formula = y ~ a * exp(b * x), se = FALSE,
              start = list(a = 1, b = 1), size=0.5, linetype = "dashed", color="black") +
  annotate("text", x = 2, y =800000, label = "atop(y == 16470.994 * e ^ {0.525*x}, R ^ 2 == 0.9995 )",
           parse = TRUE, color = "black", size =4) +
  labs(title = "Abundance Dynamic of C5 culture over days", x = "Time (days)", y = "Cell concentration (cell/mL)") +
  theme_base()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid",
                                         color = "black"))
```

So everything seems to work bu I always always have the same error message :

Warning messages:
1: Ignoring unknown parameters: start
2: In (function (formula, data = parent.frame(), start, jac = NULL,  :
No starting values specified for some parameters.
Initializing ‘a’, ‘b’ to '1.'.
Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model

I tried many times to changes the starting values but it never worked. I really really need help since I think that curve is not correct, because it is choosing starting values =1

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** you need to use `method.args=list(start(a=1, b=1))` (or whatever).

Note that you haven't given us a **minimal** example: after reading in and subsetting the data, you only need the `ggplot` call to see the problem.

In the following example I have

- streamlined things a little bit (included the `x`/`y` mappings in the main `ggplot` call so they don't have to be repeated);
- included `geom_smooth()` elements using both starting values to show that it *doesn't matter* — in this case `nlsLM` is able to get to the right solution from either set of starting values

```r
library(minpack.lm)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Day, y = C5)) +
  geom_point(data = C5_abund) +
  geom_smooth(data = C5_abund2,
              method = "nlsLM", 
              formula = y ~ a * exp(b * x),
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(start = list(a = 1, b = 1)),
              linewidth=0.5, linetype = "dashed", color="black") +
  geom_smooth(data = C5_abund2,
              method = "nlsLM", 
              formula = y ~ a * exp(b * x),
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(start=list(a=33804.52, b=0.5)),
              linewidth=2, color=adjustcolor("red", alpha.f = 0.2))
```

[image]